# Laravel 4 - foreach in foreach

Tags: php, foreach, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm displaying some content with a @foreach. But I want to display that content in a different way if this data match with any data from another @foreach...

This is my code:

```
@foreach($todasactividades as $a)
    <div class="marco-cabecera">

            @foreach($actividades as $activ)
                @if($a->id == $activ->id)
                <?php $bandera = true; ?>

                @elseif($a->id != $activ->id)
                <?php $bandera = false; ?>

                    @if($bandera)
                        {{ $a->actividad }}
                    @elseif(!$bandera)
                        {{ $a->actividad }} Something different!!
                    @endif

                @endif 
            @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

I have tried some different things, so now I think my code is a mess...

Does anybody know how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should put the two datasources together before evaluating the result in the template. This will make the template code easier and remove that business logic from it, moving it to where it is better suited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this situation in this way...

```
@foreach($todasactividades as $a)   
        <?php $bandera = 0 ?>
        @foreach($actividades as $activ)
            @if($a->id == $activ->id) 
                <?php $bandera++ ?>
            @endif
        @endforeach
        @if($bandera == 0)
            <div class="marco-fondo-blanco">
            {{ $a->actividad }}
            </div>
        @else 
            <div class="marco-fondo-gris">
            {{ $a->actividad }}
            </div>
        @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

This cleans up your code and fixes some of the logic issues.

```
@foreach($todasactividades as $a)
    <div class="marco-cabecera">
            @foreach($actividades as $activ)
                @if($a->id == $activ->id)
                    {{ $a->actividad }}
                @else
                    {{ $a->actividad }} Something different!!
                @endif 
            @endforeach
    </div> 
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do these loops inside eachother.  Make a lookup array

```
$activities = array();
@foreach($todasactividades as $a) {
    $activities[$a->id] = $a->id;
}
```

Then make your primary loop and check to see if your activity is set

```
    <div class="marco-cabecera">
    @foreach($actividades as $activ)
        @if(isset($activities[$activ->id]))
            {{ $a->actividad }}
        @else
            {{ $a->actividad }} Something different!!
        @endif
    @endforeach
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try following instead, no need to use `@if` and `<?php` tag or other variable for this):

```
@foreach($todasactividades as $a)
    <div class="marco-cabecera">
        @foreach($actividades as $activ)
            {{ $a->actividad }} 
            {{ $a->id != $activ->id ? 'Something different!!' : '' }}
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```